# Can changing one's address within the same USCIS field office delay one's US naturalization application?

Tags: usa, citizenship

Assume a US naturalization applicant moves to a new address, which they indicate on an AR-11 form. The new address is attached to the same USCIS field office as the old address. Can this address change within the same USCIS field office delay one's US naturalization application?

Comment: Of course it can. Any change in your details may trigger additional checks and reassessments. *Will* it? Who knows...

Comment: @littleadv who knows are immigration lawyers, USCIS officers, some naturalization candidates, etc.

Comment: No, they don't. They can share their experiences, anecdotal evidence, but they don't *know* how that would reflect on *your* case. I think you should handle your anxiety about your immigration process in ways other than trolling this forum. There are professional options available, lawyers and therapists alike.

Comment: @littleadv naturalization applicants sometimes talk to USCIS officers and immigration lawyers.

Comment: Not the officer handling *your* case... And even if they do, neither you nor them would know that. And even if you and them do - neither of you would know the caseload of that officer and what itches they had to scratch the morning your AR11 landed on their desk.

Comment: @littleadv does the AR11 physically land on their desk? I thought the process would be automated.

Comment: I'll refer you to my first comment.

Comment: Are you trying to decide whether to move before naturalizing?  If so, assume that your application will be delayed, decide how important that delay is to you, and decide whether the benefits of the move justify the delay.  If you're not trying to decide whether to move, then it doesn't matter whether reporting the change of address will delay the application because you already decided whether to move, so whatever impact it's going to have will be the impact it has.  (I assume that you're not considering whether to move without reporting the change of address, which would be sheer folly.)

Comment: @phoog "assume that your application will be delayed": thanks, yes I was trying to know whether this assumption is true.

Comment: If you knew if that assumption is true it wouldn't be an assumption, would it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer from [Imperium](https://www.visajourney.com/profile/115422-imperium/) on [visajourney.com](https://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/789196-can-changing-ones-address-within-the-same-uscis-field-office-delay-ones-us-naturalization-application/?tab=comments#comment-10729340):

> What matters most is what stage are you at in your naturalization process. CLAIMS4 (formarly RNACS) system is hard coded to delay a notification once SORN system trigers existence of a new event. It is automated as in it reactivates the notification once the event is completed. At this point, it will send notice with new address.

Comment: This is useless. What is CLAIMS4? What is RNACS? What is SORN? How does a delay in an event notification lead to a delay of the whole process? Does it at all? Have you posted an answer just to get upvotes, as with all the rest of your self-answered nuisance questions?

Comment: @littleadv given the lack of upvotes, it's hard to imagine that upvotes are the primary motivation.

Comment: @littleadv  CLAIMS4, RNACS, and SORN can all be easily found on Google.

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer